# finding the curvature of a curve between 1 plane and a cone at a point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am a noob at math and I had to solve this equation for an exam:
The curve Y is the intersection of the plane $x=-1$ and the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$, find the curvature at a point $P(-1,2,\sqrt{5})$

This is how I solved it:

**1.** The intersection of the plane and the cone is giving the function $f(x,y,z)=1+y^2-z^2$

**2.** I did the curvature formula $\dfrac{|| r'(t) \times r''(t)||}{||r'(t)||^3}$ and then I changed the $x,y$ values with my point.

Is it the correct way to solve it?

Comment: How can the point $ (-1, 2, \sqrt {5}) $ lie on a curve in the plane $ x = 1 $ ?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake, x=-1 , ty

Comment: This approach would work, but it requires you to properly parameterize the curve in the plane by $\vec{r}(t)$, which is not shown here.